# fast apply_along_axis equivalent in Julia

Tags: julia

Is there an equivalent to numpy's `apply_along_axis()` (or R's `apply()`)in Julia? I've got a 3D array and I would like to apply a custom function to each pair of co-ordinates of dimensions 1 and 2. The results should be in a 2D array.

Obviously, I could do two nested for loops iterating over the first and second dimension and then reshape, but I'm worried about performance.

This Example produces the output I desire (I am aware this is slightly pointless for `sum()`. It's just a dummy here:

```
test = reshape(collect(1:250), 5, 10, 5)

a=[]

for(i in 1:5)
    for(j in 1:10)
        push!(a,sum(test[i,j,:]))
    end
end

println(reshape(a, 5,10))
```

Any suggestions for a faster version?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia has the `mapslices` function which should do exactly what you want. But keep in mind that Julia is different from other languages you might know: library functions are not necessarily faster than your own code, because they may be written to a level of generality higher than what you actually need, and in Julia loops are fast. So it's quite likely that just writing out the loops will be faster.

That said, a couple of tips:

- Read the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/) section of the manual. From that you'd learn to put everything in a function, and to not use untyped arrays like `a = []`.
- The `slice` or `sub` function can avoid making a copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Also I realise the loops are much faster :( "Performance tips" is a good shout. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
f = sum  # your function here
Int[f(test[i, j, :]) for i in 1:5, j in 1:10]
```

The last line is a two-dimensional array comprehension. 
The `Int` in front is to guarantee the type of the elements; this should not be necessary if the comprehension is inside a function.

Note that you should (almost) never use untyped (`Any`) arrays, like your `a = []`, since this will be slow. You can write `a = Int[]` instead to create an empty array of `Int`s.

EDIT: Note that in Julia, loops are fast. The need for creating functions like that in Python and R comes from the inherent slowness of loops in those languages. In Julia it's much more common to just write out the loop.